# RestSharp - bad converting string to json c#

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, restsharp

Hello dunno why but when i try POST with RestSharp there is something bad with converting data.

I'm trying to post data with baselinker:

**API :**
https://api.baselinker.com/index.php?tester
When i just post with thier test on website it's good response :
[image]

But when i try do the same via  RestSharp with code :

```
public async Task xdAsync()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php");
    string token = "my API token here";


    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();




    request.AddParameter("token", token);
    request.AddParameter("method", "addProductVariant");
    request.AddParameter("application/json","{\"storage_id\":\"bl_1\",\"product_id\":\"67564668\",\"variant_id\":1055421650,\"name\":\"42\",\"quantity\":5,\"price_brutto\":599.99,\"ean\":29193201490}",ParameterType.RequestBody);


 
    var response = await client.PostAsync(request);

    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
}
```

It's give me just reponse like this :

```
{"status":"ERROR","error_code":"ERROR_STORAGE_ID","error_message":"Invalid storage identifier provided."}
```

I think there is an error with converting string or something. I tried a lot of changes without slahes ,  trying use `@` and still can't find solution maybe someone had similar problem with RestSharp or smoething?

Also when i try another method via

```
  //wyslanie requesta:
            var url = "https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json";

            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";

            httpRequest.Accept = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "My API KEY";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = @"{
                            ""addProductVariant"":{ ""storage_id"":""bl_1"",
                                                    ""product_id"":""67564668"",
                                                    ""variant_id"":""10525421650"",
                                                    ""name"":""42"",
                                                    ""quantity"":""10"",
                                                    ""price_brutto"":""599.99"",
                                                    ""ean"":""29193201490"" }
                         } ";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(data);
            }


            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

I get reposne via `httpRequest` like this :

```
{"success":"true"}
OK
```

I don't have full response in this method but it works.

Comment: A good debugging tip.  Get it working in POSTMAN (or Restsharp or whatever UI tool).  Do a "export to code" or "show me the code".  And look for all magic-values.  GET vs POST and all those pesky HEADERS (names and values).  Once you have the UI work..you "mimic" in the code.  But you mimic everything..not bits and pieces.

Comment: Once you get past this issue, note that you have `""quantity"":""10""`, `""price_brutto"":""599.99""` and `""ean"":""29193201490""`. They are all numbers, not strings in the _sample parameters_ you show

Comment: @granadaCoder thank you for suggestion. Postman is the best to do that . And give  ready code in many languages to do that :)  thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add content type

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);

.... your code

var body="{\"storage_id\":\"bl_1\",\"product_id\":\"67564668\",\"variant_id\":1055421650,\"name\":\"42\",\"quantity\":5,\"price_brutto\":599.99,\"ean\":29193201490}";

request.AddParameter("application/json",body,ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var json=response.Content;
```

Comment: So yeah, see my comment (on the question).. you'll probably see this Header in our UI tool, and you need to code it like this.  Upvote for this answer.

Comment: I just added content type and now  i have error : {"status":"ERROR","error_code":"ERROR_EMPTY_TOKEN","error_message":"No user token provided."} . Seems like not see token now.

Comment: @AdamZbudniewek I don't know what kind of token are you using, but I showed how to add  JWT token

Comment: Contet-Type should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest RestSharp, you should *not* add the body parameter like you do, neither should you add the content type header.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php");
var token = "my API token here";
var request = new RestRequest()
    .AddParameter("token", token);
    .AddParameter("method", "addProductVariant");
    .AddStringBody("\"storage_id\":\"bl_1\",\"product_id\":\"67564668\",\"variant_id\":1055421650,\"name\":\"42\",\"quantity\":5,\"price_brutto\":599.99,\"ean\":29193201490}", DataFormat.Json);

var response = await client.PostAsync(request);
```